# Нетбук в роли WiFi повторителя (WiFi repeater)

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

**Начну с описания железки**

Китайский [NoName](https://crux-arm.nu/images/wm8505.jpg) нетбук:
CPU: WM 8505 300MHz
RAM: 128 MB DDRII
DISPLAY: 7" 800*480
OS: Debian 8 armel, kernel 3.16.35(собирал специально под эту железку) без графической оболочки | по умолчанию стояла Windows CE 6.0

`WiFi` запускается через `GPIO` вот так:

```
echo "2" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/value
```

Определяется как:

```
~# lsusb  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter  

~# lsmod
rt2800usb              16933  0
rt2800lib              71365  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb               8136  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              34806  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              326656  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
led_class               2762  1 rt2x00lib
cfg80211              206612  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
```

и подтягивает `Ralink firmware v0.29`

**Софт**  
`wpa_supplicant v2.3
hostapd v2.3
dnsmasq v2.72
iptables v1.4.21
create_ap v0.4.6
isc-dhcp-server v4.3.1`

**Проделанная работа**
Настроеный и коректно работающий `wpa_supplicant` который без проблем цепляется к WiFi роутеру.

```
~# iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ON_Linux"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: F8:1A:76:7D:6E:87
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:10   Missed beacon:0


 ~# ping google.com -c3
 PING google.com (172.217.16.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
 64 bytes from bud02s25-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=19.8 ms
 64 bytes from bud02s25-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=34.5 ms
 64 bytes from bud02s25-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.110): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=24.8 ms

 --- google.com ping statistics ---
 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
 rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.890/26.440/34.545/6.085 ms
```

Вывод `rfkill list`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

[Вывод команды `iw list`](https://pastebin.com/wa5tL3CB)

Создал виртуальный адаптер  `wifiap` командой:

```
~# iw phy phy0 interface add wifiap type managed
```

и перевел его в режим `repeater`(хотя это ничего не дало по отношению с режимом `managed`)

```
~# iwconfig wifiap mode repeater
```

Запускаю точку скриптом `create_ap`

```
~# create_ap wlan0 wifiap TEST test1234 --no-virt
```

Точка создается нормально( `wlan0` переходит в режим `master`), видна устройствам и к ней можно подключится.

Делаю подключение к wifi роутеру через `wpa_supplicant`:

```
~# wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Все проходит отлично, но вылетает точка в `create_ap` с ошибкой `handle_probe_req: send failed`. Если сначала подключится к роутеру, а потом запустить `create_ap`, то получаю ошибку:

```
 ERROR: Your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and an AP at the same time
```

Для эксперимета подключил Ethernet кабель и запустил:

```
~# create_ap eth0 wlan0 TEST test1234 --no-virt
```

Точка запустилась с доступом в интернет, видна устройствам и к ней можно подключится и пользоватся Интернет, но проблема в том, что там где я хочу поставить нетбук в качестве раздатчика нет кабеля.

Вопрос: Как создать WiFi повторитель (WiFi repeater) на базе нетбука под управление Debian 8 при условии, что подлючение к сети производится только через WiFi?

Если нужно есть возможность компилировать ядро, модули, драйвера.
**P.S.** Если я переведу вопрос на англ. и задам его на [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) это будет считатся дубликатом вопроса?

**UPD:** кардинально изменил вопрос, добавил больше информации. Предыдущий вопрос удалил.

Comment: делай бридж. делай конект через hostapd. делай слейв AP тем же ssid в том же конфиге hostapd. Укажи им один бридж.

Comment: получится "универсальный репитор" как на мелких роутерах.

запуск через mode repater требует еще настройки wds

Comment: @eri что значить `слейв`?

Comment: ,ой, в линуксах это редко называют слейвом, микротик прилип.... имел ввиду "виртуальные интерфейсы" https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point_(Русский)

Comment: http://imti.co/post/145442415333/raspberry-pi-3-wifi-station-ap вот готовая инструкция

Comment: @eri к сожалению инструкция не работает у меня на железки. Не стартует dnsmasq при загрузке ругаясь на прописанный в конфиге виртуальный интерфейс.

Comment: Nov 21 12:35:46 debian dnsmasq[895]: unknown interface wfap0  
Nov 21 12:35:46 debian dnsmasq[895]: FAILED to start up

Comment: wfap0 похоже на опечатку. наверное wtap0