# linux python scapy - как дублировать пакеты полностью для усиления сигнала wifi?

Tags: python, linux, wifi, scapy

Суть задачи в том, чтобы усилить сигнал точки доступа. Копировать все пакеты и переотправлять их без расшифровки и подключения к точке доступа. Найти пакеты которые идут от точки к клиенту и наоборот и просто переотправлять их. Может есть такая программа уже и не надо использовать scapy. смотрел в сторону airodump не нашел требуемого функционала.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сделать [wi-fi репитер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741981)?

Comment: @andreymal репитер да, но без подключения к точке доступа. Для репитера полно софта, но он работает не так как мне надо. Он подключается к точке и "дублирует" ее с использованием NAT. А мне нужно  получить "усилитель" сигнала. Без подключения к точке доступа, а просто дублировать пакеты чтобы они могли идти дальше.

Comment: WDS настрой. будет без nat

Comment: кстати интересный вопрос. если забить на моралюную составляющую, то можно попробовать

Comment: @eri Так а как сделать то такой "усилитель"? Как в Scapy это все прописать? Или есть готовый софт?

Comment: готовый софт называется wpad, но вас такой не устроил)